# Bash table menu does not format well in windows wsl full screen

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a .sh Bash script that we run on ubuntu 2004 through Windows 10 WSL2. when we first open ubuntu, it's not a full-screen window and the menu looks good. As soon as we full screen the ubuntu window, the list is all messed up.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to handle default and full-screen windows?
2. Is it possible to add blank lines or control the columns/rows so we can have the all on one column, A's on another as an example using the method below?

```
echo ''
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=(
    "All Staging" 
    "All Dev" 
    "All Production" 
        
    "A- Staging"
    "A- Dev" 
    "A- Production" 
    
    "B- Staging"
    "B- Dev"
    "B- Production" 
    
    "C- Staging"
    "C- Dev"
    "C- Production"

    "D- Lab"
    "D- Dev"
    "D- Production"

    "E- Staging"
    "E- Dev"
    "E- Production"

    "Quit"

select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "All Production")
            #DO stuff
            Print_Table
        ;;
        "All Staging")
            #DO stuff
            Print_Table
        ;;
        "All Dev")
...
       ;;
```

Example without a full screen
[image]

Example in full screen
[image]

Update 1:
resize command in the small window

```
$ resize
COLUMNS=120;
LINES=42;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

resize command after fullscreen

```
$ resize
COLUMNS=207;
LINES=61;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: The messed up display looks like your terminal does not send the appropriate signal when you resize it. Try manually resetting the screen's dimensions (the `resize` command does this if you have it) or switch to a better terminal emulator to run your scripts in. The galaxy brain move, as always, is to ditch Windows entirely.

Comment: resize does appear to be working added update above